# expandable layout with recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have problem with recyclerview and ExpandableLayout , i want to collapse and expand my recyclerview not one item on it , but when expand recyclerview height is 0dp
and no show any data in the adapter

i try to used this two library and have the

https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout

https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

but get same problem expand cant see any item on recyclerview

i try to use 
 mExpandableLayout1.invalidate(); to update it but do nothing

but when i add minHeigh on recyclerview i can show one item as heigh i added

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library :

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

It has same functionality as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with this [library](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter), there is a full example [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example4Fragment.java).